# Using css style tag within Laravel blade file

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to use css in my blade.php files but I am having trouble doing so. I would like to avoid using an external css sheet. In a normal html file I can do something like this

```
<img src="/Users/rays/Desktop/Icons/Joe_Icon.png" style="width:160px;height:100px">
```

And it will generate an image for me that is resized.I am trying to do the same thing in a blade file but am having trouble.

The following code displays an image but doesn't it style it to the right dimensions, I also see the words style="width:160px;height:100px" on the screen.

```
<a href="#">{{ HTML::image("progress2/Icons/Joe_Icon.png")}} style="width:160px;height:100px"  </a>
```

This also displays an image but doesn't display the image with the right size.

```
  <style="width:160px;height:100px">
  <a href="#">{{ HTML::image("progress2/Icons/Joe_Icon.png")}} </a>
  </style>
```

And the following gets me a syntax error

```
<a href="#">{{ HTML::image("progress2/Icons/Joe_Icon.png" style="width:160px;height:100px" )}} </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
{!! HTML::image('progress2/Icons/Joe_Icon.png', 'alt', array( 'width' => 160, 'height' => 100 )) !!}
```

Also, hardcoding CSS is a bad practice. You should use CSS stylesheets and build images like this:

```
{!! HTML::image('progress2/Icons/Joe_Icon.png', 'alt', array('class' => 'progress_image')) !!}
```

Comment: That worked thank you I had been struggling with this for a while